# Exception occurs when i try to create instance of type through assembly.CreateInstance method

Tags: c#, sharepoint, exception, reflection

Exception occurs when i try to create instance of type through assembly.CreateInstance method. This is my code in which exception occurs

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll");
Type type = assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager");
object ins = assembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName);

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->     System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: serviceContext
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean ignorePrivacy)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean backwardCompatible)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName)
   at HomeWork.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\amasud\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HomeWork\HomeWork\Program.cs:line 23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know the reason why you want to create Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager object in reflective way. In your case, you have to pass SPServerContext to the constructor. Here is how you can do it.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll");
SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.Current;
Type type = assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager");
object ins = Activator.CreateInstance(type, serviceContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it, whatever type you are creating is expecting a serviceContext parameter in the constructor. You haven't set it, so it crashes.

Comment: I just checked the inner exception and it is also giving the same serviceContext exception. I am new to this stuff can you please tell how to do this ?

Comment: Would have been the answer you've already accepted, or perhaps a less elegant but more 'erm obvious approach using the ConstructorInfo class.